# Spark request max count

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a beginner on spark and I try to make a request allow me to retrieve the most visited web pages.

My request is the following

```
mostPopularWebPageDF = logDF.groupBy("webPage").agg(functions.count("webPage").alias("cntWebPage")).agg(functions.max("cntWebPage")).show()
```

With this request I retrieve only a dataframe with the max count but I want to retrieve a dataframe with this score and the  web page that holds this score

Something like that:

```
webPage            max(cntWebPage)
google.com         2
```

How can I fix my problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pyspark + sql:

```
logDF.registerTempTable("logDF")

mostPopularWebPageDF = sqlContext.sql("""select webPage, cntWebPage from (
                                            select webPage, count(*) as cntWebPage, max(count(*)) over () as maxcnt 
                                            from logDF 
                                            group by webPage) as tmp
                                            where tmp.cntWebPage = tmp.maxcnt""")
```

Maybe I can make it cleaner, but it works. I will try to optimize it.

My result:

```
webPage      cntWebPage
google.com   2
```

for dataset:

```
webPage    usersid
google.com 1
google.com 3
bing.com   10
```

Explanation: normal counting is done via grouping + count(*) function. Max of all these counts are calculated via window function, so for dataset above, immediate DataFrame /without dropping maxCount column/ is:

```
webPage    count  maxCount
google.com 2      2
bing.com   1      2
```

Then we select rows with count equal to maxCount

EDIT: I have deleted DSL version - it does not support window over () and ordering is changing result. Sorry for this bug. SQL version is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: I'm up voting this because the OP seems clueless about how things go on SO. :)

Comment: @JackR please check out update. I've discovered, that ordering in window function will change result - please use only SQL syntax. Spark currently does not have Window over () in DSL

Comment: @eliasah Thanks :) And I have upvoted your answer ;)

Comment: I guessed that as well.

Comment: This can be done by pyspark dataframe as well but will be long operation.