# Spark request avg with count

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to make a request to find the most busy day of the week on average.

I have a field day (Monday, Tuesday ...) on my dataframe.

My request is the following:

```
mostBusyDayDF = logDF.groupBy("day_week")
  .agg(functions.count("day_week").alias("cntDay"))
  .groupBy("cntDay").agg(functions.avg("cntDay").alias("avgDay"))
  .orderBy(functions.desc("avgDay")).limit(1).show()
```

The result is an avg of the sum of all count but I want to have the avg for each day.

For example:

My input

```
day_week
  Monday
  Tuesday
  Monday
  Monday
```

I want in output

```
day_week       count()        avg()
  Monday            1          1/(1+2+4+2)
  Tuesday           2          2/(1+2+4+2)
  Monday            4          4/(1+2+4+2)
  Monday            2          2/(1+2+4+2)
```

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you think about accepting this one per example ? http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/15320/5177

Comment: Is not the same thing. I want to have an avg of my count

Comment: I know that it's not the same thing but you have to accept the answers for the questions you ask and which solves your problem.

Comment: But now it's an other problem it's not the same

Comment: I'm telling you what you have to do for the other question. Not this one. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Plus considering your current question. It would be better if you provide an example input and output

Comment: Ok sorry I accept it. Thanks :) you can help me on this question?

Comment: I can try. It's still not very clear to me what you are trying to compute.

Comment: There is an example output

Comment: Still not enough. Your example output doesn't make much sense considering your query.

Comment: I count each day in my dataframe. With this count for each day I want to make the average of each day. So the countOfDay / sum(countOfDay)

Comment: @JackR Also my answer should be accepted ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817728/spark-request-max-count

Comment: It's ok :) @T.Gawęda

Comment: @eliasah can you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819124/spark-request-with-time?noredirect=1#comment68857558_40819124

Comment: I'll take a look into it tomorrow. I'm off to bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to sum the columns count first and there is many ways to do it e.g :

```
sum_count = logDF.count()
```

Once you have this sum, you can perform your group by and divide by the sum e.g :

```
mostBusyDayDF = logDF.groupBy("day_week")
       .agg(functions.count("day_week").alias("cntDay"))
       .withColumn("avgDay" , col("cntDay") / functions.lit(sum_count))
mostBusyDayDF.show()
```

**Note :** `lit` creates a Column of literal value.

Comment: what is lit please?

Comment: @JackR function - please import `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

Comment: You are the best :)